# scrolling in list view with checkbox states

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

when scrolling down with list view some checked boxes goes to false state .

i have tired several solution but I'm very confused

i want some simple code cuz i don't like to build all code from zero .

note : every row has three check boxes  so that I'm use three lists .

```
public class StudentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StudentHelper> {

final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.sams.com";
String URL = "http://sams-app.com:8080/webService/services/InsertDataWS?WSDL";
final String METHOD_NAME = "insertApsentData";
final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.sams.com/insertApsentData";

private final List<StudentHelper> StudentNamesList; // for the student names
                                                    // .
private final List<StudentHelper> StudentIdsList; // for the student ids .
private final Activity activity;
Context context;
boolean test = false;

public StudentAdapter(Activity activity,
        List<StudentHelper> StudentNamesList,
        List<StudentHelper> StudentIdsList, Context context,
        Activity listActivity1, boolean test) {
    super(activity, R.layout.activity_list, StudentNamesList);
    this.activity = listActivity1;
    this.StudentNamesList = StudentNamesList;
    this.context = context;
    this.StudentIdsList = StudentIdsList;
    this.test = test;
    // this.filter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter();
}

@Override
public StudentHelper getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position);
}

class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView StudentName;
    protected TextView StudentId;
    protected TextView Course_Name;
    protected TextView Class_id;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
    protected CheckBox checkbox1;
    protected CheckBox checkbox2;
    protected TableRow row;
}

// List<Integer> checkBoxState = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// TreeSet<Integer> checkBoxState = new TreeSet<Integer>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> checkBoxState = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
final List<Boolean> SparseBooleanArray = null;
final List<Boolean> SparseBooleanArray1 = null;
final List<Boolean> SparseBooleanArray2 = null;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rep, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.StudentName = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.TextView07);

        viewHolder.StudentId = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.TextView08);

        viewHolder.Course_Name = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        viewHolder.Class_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);

        viewHolder.checkbox1 = (CheckBox) view
                .findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);

        viewHolder.checkbox2 = (CheckBox) view
                .findViewById(R.id.CheckBox02);

        viewHolder.row = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.TableRow05);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
                "extrafine.ttf");

        Typeface fontar = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
                "extrafinear.ttf");

        viewHolder.StudentName.setTypeface(fontar);

        viewHolder.StudentId.setTypeface(font);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.row.setTag(StudentNamesList.get(position));

        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(StudentNamesList.get(position));

        viewHolder.checkbox1.setTag(StudentNamesList.get(position));

        viewHolder.checkbox2.setTag(StudentNamesList.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;

        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(StudentNamesList
                .get(position));

        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox1.setTag(StudentNamesList
                .get(position));

        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox2.setTag(StudentNamesList
                .get(position));

        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).row.setTag(StudentNamesList
                .get(position));

    }

    Button sumbit = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.sumbitbtn);
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.StudentName.setText(StudentNamesList.get(position).getName());

    holder.StudentId.setText(StudentIdsList.get(position).getName());

    holder.checkbox.setChecked(StudentNamesList.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.checkbox1
            .setChecked(StudentNamesList.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.checkbox2
            .setChecked(StudentNamesList.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.checkbox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {

                        SparseBooleanArray.add(position, true);
                        holder.checkbox.setSelected(true);
                        holder.checkbox1.setChecked(false);
                        holder.checkbox2.setChecked(false);
                        holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
                        ViewGroup row1 = (ViewGroup) holder.checkbox
                                .getParent();

                        View view1 = ((ViewGroup) row1).getChildAt(4);
                        if (view1 instanceof TextView) {

                            holder.StudentId = (TextView) view1;

                            checkBoxState.put(Integer
                                    .parseInt(holder.StudentId.getText()
                                            .toString()), 0);

                        }

                    } else if (holder.checkbox.isChecked() == false) {
                        holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rep);
                        holder.checkbox.setSelected(false);

                        ViewGroup row1 = (ViewGroup) holder.checkbox
                                .getParent();

                        View view1 = ((ViewGroup) row1).getChildAt(4);
                        if (view1 instanceof TextView) {

                            holder.StudentId = (TextView) view1;

                            checkBoxState.remove(Integer
                                    .parseInt(holder.StudentId.getText()
                                            .toString()));
                        }

                    }

                }
            });

    holder.checkbox1
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {
                        SparseBooleanArray1.add(position, true);
                        holder.checkbox1.setSelected(true);
                        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                        holder.checkbox2.setChecked(false);
                        ViewGroup row1 = (ViewGroup) holder.checkbox1
                                .getParent();

                        View view1 = ((ViewGroup) row1).getChildAt(4);
                        if (view1 instanceof TextView) {

                            holder.StudentId = (TextView) view1;

                            checkBoxState.put(Integer
                                    .parseInt(holder.StudentId.getText()
                                            .toString()), 1);
                            holder.row
                                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);

                        }

                    } else if (holder.checkbox1.isChecked() == false) {
                        holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rep);
                        holder.checkbox1.setSelected(false);

                        ViewGroup row1 = (ViewGroup) holder.checkbox1
                                .getParent();

                        View view1 = ((ViewGroup) row1).getChildAt(4);
                        if (view1 instanceof TextView) {

                            holder.StudentId = (TextView) view1;

                            checkBoxState.remove(Integer
                                    .parseInt(holder.StudentId.getText()
                                            .toString()));
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

    holder.checkbox2
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {
                        SparseBooleanArray2.add(position, true);
                        holder.checkbox2.setSelected(true);
                        holder.checkbox1.setChecked(false);
                        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                        ViewGroup row1 = (ViewGroup) holder.checkbox1
                                .getParent();

                        View view1 = ((ViewGroup) row1).getChildAt(4);
                        if (view1 instanceof TextView) {

                            holder.StudentId = (TextView) view1;

                            checkBoxState.put(Integer
                                    .parseInt(holder.StudentId.getText()
                                            .toString()), 2);
                            holder.row
                                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                        }
                    } else if (holder.checkbox2.isChecked() == false) {
                        holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rep);
                        holder.checkbox2.setSelected(false);

                        ViewGroup row1 = (ViewGroup) holder.checkbox2
                                .getParent();

                        View view1 = ((ViewGroup) row1).getChildAt(4);
                        if (view1 instanceof TextView) {

                            holder.StudentId = (TextView) view1;

                            checkBoxState.remove(Integer
                                    .parseInt(holder.StudentId.getText()
                                            .toString()));
                        }

                    }

                }
            });

    /*
     * if(test){
     * 
     * 
     * for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> mapEntry : checkBoxState
     * .entrySet()){
     * 
     * checkBoxState.remove(mapEntry.getKey());
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * 
     * }
     */

    holder.checkbox.setChecked(SparseBooleanArray.get(position));
    // holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);

    holder.checkbox1.setChecked(SparseBooleanArray1.get(position));
    // holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);

    holder.checkbox2.setChecked(SparseBooleanArray2.get(position));
    // holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);

    sumbit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkBoxState.isEmpty()) {

                Toast.makeText(activity, "OOOh it's empaty ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            else {

                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
                progressDialog
                        .setMessage("جاري ارسال البيانات ، الرجاء الانتظار");
                progressDialog.show();

                SendListSync asynTask = new SendListSync(context, activity,
                        checkBoxState, progressDialog);
                asynTask.execute();

            }

        }
    });

    return view;

}

}
```

Comment: save the states of checkboxes in an array in getview function check if you need to check / uncheck the checkbox and set it accordingly. u dont have to do special in the UI but save the state in some data set

Comment: why to use array not using list ? and how to check and unchecked , using if statement ? it going to be nullpointerec